# Vs code debugging redirection to default chrome window instead of configured one

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Everytime I run the chrome developer tools, I get redirected to a default chrome window instead one with my account and react dev tools on it.
If somebody knows how to change this, an answer would be greatly appreciated.
This is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you install the Debuguer For Chrome extension ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome ?

Comment: Yes, i have installed the extension.